# How can i display option dynamically in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

product.js

```
 Qty: <select value={qty} onChange={(e) => { setQty(e.target.value) }}>
       {[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
           <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>  ===> here i want to show option according to product.countInStock
             {x + 1}
           </option>
        ))}
       </select>
```

I want to display options dynamically I get product.countInStock a number like 2,3 I want if the number is 3 then option must be 1,2,3 if the number is 2 like option must be 1,2. How can I display option dynamically

Comment: What is the problem? this code seems fine

Comment: Still, it's not displaying options according to the product.countInStock it only shows option 1 irrespective of the product.countInStock

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your **product.countInStock** value type is String. That's why you didn't get the preferable result. If you passing the String value into array, the output of this code `[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()]` is 0. Your string value take as one element of Array. Because of that in your select option list it will show only "1".

To convert **product.countInStock** this value into integer value you can use parseInt() method. whole code snippets like this,

```
<select value={qty} onChange={e => setQty(e.target.value) }>
    {[...Array(parseInt(product.countInStock)).keys()].map(
        (x) => (
            <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>{x + 1}</option>
        )
    )}
</select>
```

Make sure your **product.countInStock** is Integer value to get the your preferable result.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work if the countInStock is updated properly.

Note that if the product is part of your state, you might need to return a new product object with the updated value of countInStock to trigger proper change detection. `this.setState({product: {...product, countInStock: newValue}})` or `setProduct({..product, countInStock: newValue})` depending on whether you use class or functional components.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({ countInStock: 2 });
  const setProductCount = (e) =>
    setProduct({ ...product, countInStock: +e.target.value });
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        Set Product count:
        <select onChange={setProductCount}>
          <option value="1"> 1 </option>
          <option value="2"> 2 </option>
          <option value="3"> 3 </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        Product count dropdown
        <select>
          {[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
            <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
              {x + 1}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am working on some e-commerce tools on react and ts. Figuring mostly everything from scratch regarding ts/tsx.

This might solve your issue

---

```
 <select
           value={qty}
                    onChange={(e) => setQty(parseInt(e.target.value))}
                  >
                    {[...(Array(product.countInStock).keys() as any)].map(
                      (x) => (
                        <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                          {x + 1}
                        </option>
                      )
                    )}
                  </select>
```